# Creating range (corridor) plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the example available through [r-statistics](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Stacked%20Area%20Chart) website, I would like to modify it create a range plot

## Example

```
# Notes -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Stacked are chart
# Source: http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Stacked%20Area%20Chart

# Graphic -----------------------------------------------------------------

library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
theme_set(theme_bw())

df <- economics[, c("date", "psavert", "uempmed")]
df <- df[lubridate::year(df$date) %in% c(1967:1981),]

# labels and breaks for X axis text
brks <- df$date[seq(1, length(df$date), 12)]
lbls <- lubridate::year(brks)

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = date)) +
    geom_area(aes(y = psavert + uempmed, fill = "psavert")) +
    geom_area(aes(y = uempmed, fill = "uempmed")) +
    labs(
        title = "Area Chart of Returns Percentage",
        subtitle = "From Wide Data format",
        caption = "Source: Economics",
        y = "Returns %"
    ) +  # title and caption
    scale_x_date(labels = lbls, breaks = brks) +  # change to monthly ticks and labels
    scale_fill_manual(name = "",
                      values = c("psavert" = "#00ba38", "uempmed" = "#f8766d")) +  # line color
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  # turn off minor grid
```

## Desired results

[image: Example range plot]

## Attempts

### `"white"`

Setting one series colour to white, is close but I would like to make the grid visible. Controlling legend could be easily done later.

[image: attempt 1]

Comment: try `geom_ribbon` instead of `geom_area`

Comment: This is just a `geom_ribbon`, where the `ymin` is whatever the lowest value is and `ymax` is the upper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure need to use [`geom_ribbon`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html).

Adopted from the docs:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level - 1, ymax = level + 1), fill = "grey70") +
  geom_line(aes(y = level))
```